# ListView Item doesn't expand-collapse height in Xamarin Forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a List View. In ListView I have ListViewCell. ListViewCell have expand-Collapse functionality. There are few problems in expand collapse behaviours.

1- If I expand first item, it works fine. But If I expand second item first and expand first item, it first item goes behind. See Case-1 in screen shot.

2- If I click on list view item, it show in gray color for a second. I want to stop this. It should not change and color when user click on any cell. Case-2

3- If I expand first item and collapse it again. It collapse but it keep white space between second and first item.

I have noticed this behavior. Above issue resolve if I scroll down and up. Well, in ideal case, user doesn't scroll up and down after every operation :D

Note: I have Entry, DatePicker and Buttons in ListViewCell. User must be able to input in it.

Here is my code. I have also attached screen shot. Please suggest

### Main Page List View

```
<ListView x:Name="WorkHistoryListView"
    ItemsSource="{Binding WorkHistoryList}"
    HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
    VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
    SeparatorVisibility="None"
    ItemTapped="OnListViewItemTapped"
    Margin="10"
    HasUnevenRows = "true"
    IsPullToRefreshEnabled="False">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <localview:WorkHistoryViewCell />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

### WorkHistoryViewCell.xaml

```
<StackLayout Margin="0" Padding="0">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <!-- Blue heading-->
        <StackLayout Margin="0" Padding="0" Grid.Row="0" BackgroundColor="#367fa9">
            <Grid HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" 
      Padding="15" RowSpacing="10" Margin="0" BackgroundColor="Transparent">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                <Label Text="{Binding Name}" HorizontalOptions="Center" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0"/>
                <Label Text="{Binding Date}" HorizontalOptions="Center" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1"/>
                <Label Text="+" HorizontalOptions="End" VerticalOptions="Center" Grid.Column="2" x:Name="LabelCollapse" Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="2" FontFamily="Roboto">
                    <Label.GestureRecognizers>
                        <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="LabelOpenCommand"/>
                    </Label.GestureRecognizers>
                </Label>
            </Grid>
        </StackLayout>
        <StackLayout Margin="0" Padding="0" Grid.Row="1" x:Name="FrameVisible">
            <Frame Margin="0" Padding="0" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" BackgroundColor="White" OutlineColor="Gray">
                <StackLayout Margin="0" VerticalOptions="Fill" Padding="20" IsVisible="{Binding IsWeekly}">
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.Resources>
                            <ResourceDictionary>
                                <local:InvertBooleanConverter x:Key="invertBooleanConverter" />
                                <Style x:Key="LabelStyle" TargetType="Label">
                                    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="15"/>
                                    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Roboto"/>
                                    <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="White"/>
                                </Style>
                            </ResourceDictionary>
                        </Grid.Resources>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="125"></ColumnDefinition>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="auto"></RowDefinition>
                            <RowDefinition Height="auto"></RowDefinition>
                            <RowDefinition Height="auto"></RowDefinition>
                            <RowDefinition Height="auto"></RowDefinition>
                            <RowDefinition Height="auto"></RowDefinition>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Image Source="EditLog.png" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" HorizontalOptions="End" VerticalOptions="Center"
                                HeightRequest="24">
                            <Image.GestureRecognizers>
                                <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="OnImageViewItemTapped"/>
                            </Image.GestureRecognizers>
                        </Image>
                        <Label Text="Date" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Style="{StaticResource LabelStyle}" 
                               TextColor="Black" FontFamily="Roboto" Margin="0" />
                        <local:ExtendedDatePicker TextColor="LightGray" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Row="1"
                            IsEnabled="False" Date="{Binding Date}" BackgroundColor="White">
                            <DatePicker.Format>dd/MM/yyyy</DatePicker.Format>
                        </local:ExtendedDatePicker>

                        <Label Text="Pay" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="2"  Style="{StaticResource LabelStyle}"
                               TextColor="Black" FontFamily="Roboto" Margin="0,10,0,0" />

                        <local:CustomEntry Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="3" Margin="0,10,0,0" WidthRequest="150" Text="{Binding Pay}"
                            Style="{StaticResource LabelStyle}" TextColor="Black"  HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"/>

                        <Button Text="Submit" BorderRadius="18" TextColor="White" Command="{Binding SubmitWeeklyCommand}" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="4" FontFamily="Roboto"/>
                    </Grid>
                </StackLayout>
            </Frame>
        </StackLayout>
    </Grid>
</StackLayout>
```

### WorkHistoryViewCell.xaml.cs //Command to expand collapse

```
private void LabelOpenCommand(object sender,TappedEventArgs e)
{
    if (LabelCollapse.Text == "+")
    {
        FrameVisible.IsVisible = false;
        LabelCollapse.Text = "-";
        FrameVisible.IsVisible = true;
    }
    else
    {
        FrameVisible.IsVisible = true;
        LabelCollapse.Text = "+";
        FrameVisible.IsVisible = false;
    }
}
```

Screenshot
[image]

Answer (score 3):

It happens 'cause the **cell's height** is calculated only on the first rendering. After that, the changes affect just the inner layout view.

Try call `ForceUpdateSize();` at the end of your current `TappedCommand`'s logic. It'll force the entire cell to recalculate its bounds.

The code should look like:

```
private void LabelOpenCommand(object sender,TappedEventArgs e)
{
    if (LabelCollapse.Text == "+")
    {
        FrameVisible.IsVisible = false;
        LabelCollapse.Text = "-";
        FrameVisible.IsVisible = true;
    }
    else
    {
        FrameVisible.IsVisible = true;
        LabelCollapse.Text = "+";
        FrameVisible.IsVisible = false;
    }

    ForceUpdateSize
}
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks. `ForceUpdateSize` takes 2-3 seconds to get updated size. Usually, Accordian should not take such time as there is operation exists rather hide show. So, it is hard to explain if someone ask me why it is taking time. Please suggest your thoughts!

Comment: It shouldn't take much time, indeed. The whole `ViewCell` seems very heavy, but even thus 2-3 seconds is unacceptable. Have you tried to do it asynchronously? Are you talking for [@Developer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9299162/developer)?

Comment: @DiegoRafaelSouza I have also reviewed this. For the first time, it take 1-2 seconds which is fine I guess. If user tries to expand collapse for 2-3 times, it becomes very slow and takes 3-4 seconds to expand-collapse. This delay issue is only with iOS. It is working fine in UWP and Android. I think it should work fine in iOS as it is our primary target. You have mention about asynchronously. How can I do that? I have put exact code as you have given in answer. Can you plz update your answer with Asynchronous code? Thanks.

Comment: @Developer I'm sorry for late. It's just to change the method's signature to `private async void LabelOpenCommand(...) { ... }`. I haven't tryied it on iOS, just on android, and it's response is fast enough.

Comment: @DiegoRafaelSouza, This doesn't make any change. Yes, you are right, it work very fast in Android. It still takes time in iOS. I have tried to put this line `CachingStrategy="RecycleElement` in my Listview and it start to work fine. However it start another issue: When I expand first item(viewcell), it also expand other cell which is on next screen. Any suggestions?