# Xamarin forms: Expansion and collapse is not working for list view in iOS

Tags: listview, xamarin.forms

I am listing some items on the UI. If I tap on an item it will expand and show its details. I set everything on the UI including details initially and hide the details part. When I tap on the item I change the visibility of the details and showing it on UI. This feature is working fine on android and breaking in ios. I have uploaded a sample project [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1O-_sTChePkYFoqlZ6LjMHdJcIwxq_66j/view?usp=sharing) for reference.

**Screenshot:**

[image]

**Xaml.cs**

```cs
    private void ItemTapped(object sender, ItemTappedEventArgs e)
    {
        var selectedItem = (Contact)e.Item;
        if (selectedItem != null)
        {
            if (phoneId == selectedItem.phoneOne)
            {
                Hide(selectedItem);
                phoneId = "";
            }
            else
            {
                Open(selectedItem);
            }
        }
        addressbook_listview.SelectedItem = null;
    }

    private void Open(Contact selectedItem)
    {
        
        foreach (var item in contactsList)
        {
            item.PhoneVisibility = false;
        }
        selectedItem.PhoneVisibility = true;
        phoneId = selectedItem.phoneOne;
    }
    
    private void Hide(Contact selectedItem)
    {
        selectedItem.PhoneVisibility = false;
    }
```

**Xaml**

```xml
    <ListView   
        x:Name="addressbook_listview"
        Grid.Row="1"
        BackgroundColor="Black"
        ItemTapped="addressbook_listview_ItemTapped"
        SelectionMode="None"
        HasUnevenRows="True">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ViewCell>
                    <StackLayout 
                        Padding="10"
                        Orientation="Vertical">

                        <StackLayout
                                Grid.Column="1"
                                VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                                Margin="5,0,0,0">

                            <Label 
                                    Text="{Binding contactName}"
                                    TextColor="White">
                                <Label.FontSize>
                                    <OnIdiom x:TypeArguments="x:Double">
                                        <OnIdiom.Phone>15</OnIdiom.Phone>
                                        <OnIdiom.Tablet>20</OnIdiom.Tablet>
                                        <OnIdiom.Desktop>15</OnIdiom.Desktop>
                                    </OnIdiom>
                                </Label.FontSize>
                            </Label>

                            <Label 
                                    Text="{Binding phoneOne}"
                                    TextColor="White">
                                <Label.FontSize>
                                    <OnIdiom x:TypeArguments="x:Double">
                                        <OnIdiom.Phone>15</OnIdiom.Phone>
                                        <OnIdiom.Tablet>20</OnIdiom.Tablet>
                                        <OnIdiom.Desktop>15</OnIdiom.Desktop>
                                    </OnIdiom>
                                </Label.FontSize>
                            </Label>
                        </StackLayout>

                        <StackLayout 
                            HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                            Margin="0,10,0,0"
                            IsVisible="{Binding PhoneVisibility}"
                            Orientation="Vertical">

                            <StackLayout 
                                Orientation="Horizontal">

                                <Label 
                                    Text="Phone 1"
                                    TextColor="White">
                                    <Label.FontSize>
                                        <OnIdiom x:TypeArguments="x:Double">
                                            <OnIdiom.Phone>15</OnIdiom.Phone>
                                            <OnIdiom.Tablet>20</OnIdiom.Tablet>
                                            <OnIdiom.Desktop>15</OnIdiom.Desktop>
                                        </OnIdiom>
                                    </Label.FontSize>
                                </Label>

                                    <Label 
                                    Text="{Binding phoneOne}"
                                    TextColor="White">
                                    <Label.FontSize>
                                        <OnIdiom x:TypeArguments="x:Double">
                                            <OnIdiom.Phone>15</OnIdiom.Phone>
                                            <OnIdiom.Tablet>20</OnIdiom.Tablet>
                                            <OnIdiom.Desktop>15</OnIdiom.Desktop>
                                        </OnIdiom>
                                    </Label.FontSize>
                                </Label>

                            </StackLayout>

                            <BoxView HeightRequest="0.5"
                                     HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"/>

                            <StackLayout
                                Orientation="Horizontal">

                                <Label 
                                    Text="Phone 2"
                                     TextColor="White">
                                    <Label.FontSize>
                                        <OnIdiom x:TypeArguments="x:Double">
                                            <OnIdiom.Phone>15</OnIdiom.Phone>
                                            <OnIdiom.Tablet>20</OnIdiom.Tablet>
                                            <OnIdiom.Desktop>15</OnIdiom.Desktop>
                                        </OnIdiom>
                                    </Label.FontSize>
                                </Label>

                                <Label 
                                    Text="{Binding phoneTwo}"
                                    TextColor="White">
                                    <Label.FontSize>
                                        <OnIdiom x:TypeArguments="x:Double">
                                            <OnIdiom.Phone>15</OnIdiom.Phone>
                                            <OnIdiom.Tablet>20</OnIdiom.Tablet>
                                            <OnIdiom.Desktop>15</OnIdiom.Desktop>
                                        </OnIdiom>
                                    </Label.FontSize>
                                </Label>
                            </StackLayout>
                        </StackLayout>
                    </StackLayout>
                </ViewCell>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <ListView.Footer>
            <Label/>
        </ListView.Footer>
    </ListView>
```

Comment: Got a perfect solution from this thread. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/512700/xamarin-forms-expansion-and-collapse-is-not-workin.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known issue which is pointed by @Shaw.

You can call `ViewCell.ForceUpdateSize` to forcely update the height of the cell .

The first step is to remove `ItemTapped` and use  `Tap gesture` instead .

Add a `TapGestureRecognizer` on the root stackLayout in the ItemTemplate.

###### xaml

```
<ViewCell x:Name="cell" >
        <StackLayout 
             Padding="10"
             Orientation="Vertical">
             <StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
                  <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="TapGestureRecognizer_Tapped"/>
             </StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
```

###### code behind.

```
  private void TapGestureRecognizer_Tapped(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            var stack = sender as StackLayout;
            var selectedItem = stack.BindingContext as Contact;

            if (selectedItem != null)
            {
                if (phoneId == selectedItem.phoneOne)
                {
                    HideMessageBody(selectedItem);
                    phoneId = "";
                }
                else
                {
                    OpenMessageBody(selectedItem);
                }
            }
            addressbook_listview.SelectedItem = null;         

            (stack.Parent as ViewCell).ForceUpdateSize();   //add this line 
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

In short: **Use CollectionView instead of ListView**.

I assume this is a known issue, like questions [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51086740/listview-item-doesnt-expand-collapse-height-in-xamarin-forms) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59792305/listview-doesnt-update-cell-height-in-android-and-ios), but not properly answered there.
So decided to move to CollectionView, as supposed to be recommanded officially.

Things I have changed here:

- Use `CollectionView`
- Move tap event to `TapGestureRecognizer`
- Remove "Grid" in xaml
- Make list binding to xaml, and binding to itself in xaml.cs
- Binding list should be a public property, not field
- One last thing: update to Xamarin.Forms 5.0.0.2012 (and Android setting)

Without new XF package, the collection view has another issue when updating the height (run without updating XF on iOS, which solved this question though).
I assume that is also a known issue, so upgrade the XF package fixed that,
but which requires updating "Target Android version" as well.
(Some code still could be refactored but working now)

**MainPage.xaml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage
    x:Class="ExpanderDemo.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml">
    <StackLayout>
        <CollectionView
            x:Name="addressbook_listview"
            BackgroundColor="Black"
            ItemSizingStrategy="MeasureAllItems"
            ItemsSource="{Binding contactsList}"
            SelectionMode="None">
            <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackLayout Padding="10" Orientation="Vertical">
                        <StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
                            <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="addressbook_listview_ItemTapped" />
                        </StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>

                        <StackLayout Margin="5,0,0,0">

                            <Label Text="{Binding contactName}" TextColor="White">
                                <Label.FontSize>
                                    <OnIdiom x:TypeArguments="x:Double">
                                        <OnIdiom.Phone>15</OnIdiom.Phone>
                                        <OnIdiom.Tablet>20</OnIdiom.Tablet>
                                        <OnIdiom.Desktop>15</OnIdiom.Desktop>
                                    </OnIdiom>
                                </Label.FontSize>
                            </Label>

                            <Label Text="{Binding phoneOne}" TextColor="White">
                                <Label.FontSize>
                                    <OnIdiom x:TypeArguments="x:Double">
                                        <OnIdiom.Phone>15</OnIdiom.Phone>
                                        <OnIdiom.Tablet>20</OnIdiom.Tablet>
                                        <OnIdiom.Desktop>15</OnIdiom.Desktop>
                                    </OnIdiom>
                                </Label.FontSize>
                            </Label>
                        </StackLayout>

                        <StackLayout
                            Margin="0,10,0,0"
                            HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                            IsVisible="{Binding PhoneVisibility}"
                            Orientation="Vertical">

                            <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">

                                <Label Text="Phone 1" TextColor="White">
                                    <Label.FontSize>
                                        <OnIdiom x:TypeArguments="x:Double">
                                            <OnIdiom.Phone>15</OnIdiom.Phone>
                                            <OnIdiom.Tablet>20</OnIdiom.Tablet>
                                            <OnIdiom.Desktop>15</OnIdiom.Desktop>
                                        </OnIdiom>
                                    </Label.FontSize>
                                </Label>

                                <Label Text="{Binding phoneOne}" TextColor="White">
                                    <Label.FontSize>
                                        <OnIdiom x:TypeArguments="x:Double">
                                            <OnIdiom.Phone>15</OnIdiom.Phone>
                                            <OnIdiom.Tablet>20</OnIdiom.Tablet>
                                            <OnIdiom.Desktop>15</OnIdiom.Desktop>
                                        </OnIdiom>
                                    </Label.FontSize>
                                </Label>

                            </StackLayout>

                            <BoxView HeightRequest="0.5" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" />

                            <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">

                                <Label Text="Phone 2" TextColor="White">
                                    <Label.FontSize>
                                        <OnIdiom x:TypeArguments="x:Double">
                                            <OnIdiom.Phone>15</OnIdiom.Phone>
                                            <OnIdiom.Tablet>20</OnIdiom.Tablet>
                                            <OnIdiom.Desktop>15</OnIdiom.Desktop>
                                        </OnIdiom>
                                    </Label.FontSize>
                                </Label>

                                <Label Text="{Binding phoneTwo}" TextColor="White">
                                    <Label.FontSize>
                                        <OnIdiom x:TypeArguments="x:Double">
                                            <OnIdiom.Phone>15</OnIdiom.Phone>
                                            <OnIdiom.Tablet>20</OnIdiom.Tablet>
                                            <OnIdiom.Desktop>15</OnIdiom.Desktop>
                                        </OnIdiom>
                                    </Label.FontSize>
                                </Label>
                            </StackLayout>
                        </StackLayout>
                    </StackLayout>
                </DataTemplate>
            </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
            <CollectionView.Footer>
                <Label />
            </CollectionView.Footer>
        </CollectionView>
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

**MainPage.xaml.cs**

```c#
using System;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace ExpanderDemo
{
    public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
    {
        private string phoneId;

        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            contactsList = new ObservableCollection<Contact>();
            AddNumber();
            BindingContext = this;
        }

        public ObservableCollection<Contact> contactsList { get; set; }

        private void AddNumber()
        {
            contactsList.Add(new Contact() { contactName = "Smith", phoneOne = "+1 1234567952", phoneTwo = "1478523690", PhoneVisibility = false });
            contactsList.Add(new Contact() { contactName = "Brent", phoneOne = "+1 1234568852", phoneTwo = "1478577690", PhoneVisibility = false });
            contactsList.Add(new Contact() { contactName = "Finch", phoneOne = "+1 1234560052", phoneTwo = "1478529690", PhoneVisibility = false });
            //addressbook_listview.ItemsSource = contactsList;
        }

        private void addressbook_listview_ItemTapped(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var layout = sender as StackLayout;
            var selectedItem = layout.BindingContext as Contact;

            //var selectedItem = (Contact)e.Item;
            if (selectedItem != null)
            {
                if (phoneId == selectedItem.phoneOne)
                {
                    HideMessageBody(selectedItem);
                    phoneId = "";
                }
                else
                {
                    OpenMessageBody(selectedItem);
                }
            }
            addressbook_listview.SelectedItem = null;
        }

        private void HideMessageBody(Contact selectedItem)
        {
            selectedItem.PhoneVisibility = false;
        }

        private void OpenMessageBody(Contact selectedItem)
        {
            foreach (var item in contactsList)
            {
                item.PhoneVisibility = false;
            }
            selectedItem.PhoneVisibility = true;
            phoneId = selectedItem.phoneOne;
        }
    }
}
```

Android two settings after updating XF

[image: project property]

[image: Manifest]

---

**Test result**

[image: Android]

[image: iOS]

(Please ignore the color on ios when I tested locally.)

Comment: Thanks for your response. In the demo project, I have added only 3 items. On my actual project, I am listing few items first, when scroll down and reaches the bottom I will fetch more items using the `ItemAppearing` event of listview. Is any same kind of events are available on `colectionview` to detect the end of items? I checked this, but no luck. So is there any way to solve this with `listview` itself?

Comment: That is actually a different question from ios list height. But check [this vedio](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sZq8K_64bc0) or [the docs link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/collectionview/populate-data#load-data-incrementally), which can be achieved by checking the threshold in the collection. Or just post a new Q so we can talk with some real code.